# go test ./... missing tests in subfolders

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

Running `go test -v ./...` from the root directory misses some tests in the folders of my project.

My file structure is as follows

```
.
├── cmd
│   └── Myapp
│       ├── config_test.go
│       └── main.go
├── config.yml
├── Myapp
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── images
│   └── Dockerfile.dev
├── kubernetes
│   └── deployment.yml
├── LICENSE.md
├── pkg
│   └── AFolder
│       ├── Bookmark.go
│       ├── Bookmark_test.go
│       ├── go.mod
│       ├── go.sum
│       ├── end.go
│       ├── end.go
│       ├── Handler.go
│       ├── Handler_test.go
│       ├── UpdateHandler.go
│       └── UpdateHandler_test.go
├── README.md
├── renovate.json
└── skaffold.yaml
```

The location is `../go/src/Myapp` and the go path is `../go`

I can build from the root fine with `go build ./...` and creates a binary.

But running `go test -v ./...` will only run the tests in the `config_test.go` and miss out on the tests in the pkg subfolders.

A problem with the file structure would be my first suspicion. But I am not sure how to go about fixing it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by go.mod file in AFolder folder.

The ./... pattern matches all the packages within the current module. AFolder is not the current module as it has its own go.mod file. In other words, unit test exclude all the subfolders with a go.mod file.

`go test all` will test all the dependencies. However, this is time consuming and might be unnecessary .

In my project, I just create go.mod file in root folder. For example:

1. In root folder run `go mod init github.com/cyrilzh/myproject`
2. Create sub folder "sub" and create code with package named sub
3. In the project, reference the sub package like this:

   import "github.com/cyrilzh/myproject/sub"

For more information, please refer to

[golang wiki: how to define a module](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-define-a-module)

Comment: I have tried that in the past and am getting the error `go: github.com/Afolder (replaced by ./pkg/Afolder): reading pkg/Afolder/go.mod: MyProject/pkg/Afolder/go.mod: no such file or directory` which seems to imply that i need the extra go.mod files

Comment: This is because there is a "replace" entry in your go.mod file in root folder. If you just init go module in root folder, it is not necessary to edit the go.mod file to import local packages.